# UISwipeGestureRecognizer to obtain start and end location

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS/Swift the `UIGestureRecognizer` for [swiping](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer) has `location` methods that

> determine the location where a swipe begin.

I have looked through the doc but I cannot see how to obtain both the start and end location of the swipe. I would like to figure out the (x,y) coordinates within the view of both the start and end. I tried `location(ofTouch: )` with different values for `ofTouch` but that gives me the same value when swiping in the simulator.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You could subclass the swipe gesture recognizer, and override `touchesBegan` to store the start location.

Comment: But the start location I already get. It's the end location that I am unable to obtain.

Comment: Then maybe `touchesMoved` and store the most recent position in an instance variable.

Comment: Yes, that does the trick! Thanks.

Comment: OK, I'll put it to the Answer section, then you can accept it to let others know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and override `touchesMoved`. Here, you can simply store the last value:

```
class MySwipeGestureRecognizer:UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
  var lastTouches:Set<UITouch>?

  override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    lastTouches = touches
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with:event)
  }
}
```

Then, when the gesture fires, evaluate the `lastTouches` property.

Comment: I missed the `super.touchesMoved()` call, which caused `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Doesn't `lastTouches = touches` overwrite `lastTouches`? In my trials it looks like `touches` simply contains a single `UITouch`.